# Updating Overpass-API database with local changes file

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a local OSM server and its data is stored in `openstreetmap` PostgreSQL database. Also I have Overpass-API installed for the local OSM server (using [this](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation) tutorial).

The `openstreetmap` database is sometimes updated by changes that users of the the local OSM server make in edit mode (by `iD` editor). But Overpass-API uses its own database, so I need to periodically sync these two databases.

I have already populated the Overpass-API database with `openstreetmap` database' data:

```bsh
cd /home/rion/openstreetmap

# Dump all data from the openstreetmap database.
osmosis --read-apidb host="localhost" database="openstreetmap" \
user="rion" password="password" validateSchemaVersion="no" \
--write-xml file="main-database-dump.xml"

# Compress this dump.
bzip2 -c main-database-dump.xml > main-database-dump.xml.bz2

# Specify paths to Overpass-API's executable, database, replicate files.
EXEC_DIR="/home/rion/openstreetmap/Overpass-API/build"
DB_DIR="/home/rion/openstreetmap/Overpass-API/build/db"
REPLICATE_DIR="/home/rion/openstreetmap/Overpass-API/build/replicate"

# Upload the dump to Overpass-API database.
./Overpass-API/src/bin/init_osm3s.sh main-database-dump.xml.bz2 $DB_DIR $EXEC_DIR
```

---

So, after some changes made in the `openstreetmap` database, I need to upload them to Overpass-API database, too. I use this command to pull out the `openstreetmap` database' changes to xml file:

```bsh
# Specify dates between which I will read openstreetmap database' changes.
NOW=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
HOUR_AGO=$(date -u -d '1 hour ago' +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")

# Read openstreetmap database' changes between $HOUR_AGO and $NOW dates.
osmosis --read-apidb-change host="localhost" database="openstreetmap" \
user="rion" password="password" intervalBegin=$HOUR_AGO \
intervalEnd=$NOW validateSchemaVersion="no" \
--write-xml-change file="main-database-changes.xml"

# Compress the changes file.
bzip2 -c main-database-changes.xml > main-database-changes.xml.bz2
```

So now I have the compressed xml changes file and need to upload it to the Overpass-API database. So the question is: how to do it?

I know that there is a `./Overpass-API/build/bin/update_database` util, but how to use it? I've tried to use it this way:

```bsh
./Overpass-API/build/bin/update_database --db-dir=$DB_DIR \
main-database-changes.xml.bz2
```

But it gives me an error:

```bsh
Unkown argument: main-database-changes.xml.bz2

Usage: update_database [--db-dir=DIR] [--version=VER]
[--meta|--keep-attic] [--flush_size=FLUSH_SIZE]
[--compression-method=(no|gz)] [--map-compression-method=(no|gz)]
```

**How do I use the `update_database` util with a local changes file or are there some other utils to do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the error message: you need to provide an OSM file in XML format (not xml.bz2 !) via standard input:

```
update_database --db-dir=$DB_DIR < main-database-changes.xml
```

Please note that `update_database` can only be used for the initial database setup(!). To apply subsequent changes, you have to use the `update_from_dir` binary instead to apply your osc files

Take a look at https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/blob/master/src/bin/fetch_osc_and_apply.sh how this is implemented. Take particular note of the `--flush-size=0` parameter, and the `--version` parameter, which is used to provide a meaningful timestamp in your query response.

Comment: Thank you, the command worked! But I had a running dispatcher and had to kill it to run this command, then started it again. I don't think that my solution was correct, because I need the dispatcher to execute Overpass-API queries. So I'll try to deliver updates to the Overpass-API database via dispatcher. I'll try to understand how to do it and write here soon.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I couldn't understand how to update Overpass-API database via dispatcher, so I have used the following workaround. I've written a bash script which will be executed every midnight by `cron`. I know that it's not a good way, but it works, at least. Maybe someone will post here a better solution.

**Bash script (`sync_overpass.sh`)**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Need this PATH variable to use Osmosis in a cron task.
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/rion/openstreetmap/osmosis/bin"

cd /home/rion/openstreetmap

# Remove an old openstreetmap changes file if it exists.
rm sync_osm_databases/main-database-daily-changes.xml

# Specify paths to Overpass-API executable & database files.
EXEC_DIR="/home/rion/openstreetmap/Overpass-API/build"
DB_DIR="/home/rion/openstreetmap/Overpass-API/build/db"

# Specify dates between which I will read openstreetmap database' changes.
NOW=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
DAY_AGO=$(date -u -d '1 day ago' +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")

# Get the running dispatcher's pid.
DISPATCHER_PID=$(pgrep -f Overpass-API/build/bin/dispatcher)

# Get openstreetmap database' daily changes.
osmosis --read-apidb-change host="localhost" database="openstreetmap" \
user="rion" password="password" intervalBegin=$DAY_AGO intervalEnd=$NOW \
validateSchemaVersion="no" --write-xml-change \
file="sync_osm_databases/main-database-daily-changes.xml"

# Kill the dispatcher and delete its lock files.
kill $DISPATCHER_PID
rm $DB_DIR/osm3s_v0.7.54_osm_base
rm /dev/shm/osm3s_v0.7.54_osm_base

# Upload changes to Overpass-API database.
$EXEC_DIR/bin/update_database --db-dir=$DB_DIR --meta=no \
< sync_osm_databases/main-database-daily-changes.xml

# Start the dispatcher.
nohup $EXEC_DIR/bin/dispatcher --osm-base --db-dir=$DB_DIR --meta &
```

**`cron` task:**

```bsh
0 0 * * * /home/rion/openstreetmap/sync_osm_databases/sync_overpass.sh
```

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer. In short, use update_from_dir instead of update_database to update your database.

Comment: @mmd, thank you, I'll try to use `update_from_dir` instead of `update_database`.